# HealthKit: How can I read the HKMetadataKeyWeatherCondition from a workout sample's Metadata?

Tags: swift, metadata, healthkit

I'm playing around with Apple's async/await HealthKit code and I cannot access some of the Metadata, specifically, the [HKMetadataKeyWeatherCondition](https://(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeyweathercondition)). In the code below, I print out the HealthKit sample Metadata and I can see the temperature and the humidity but not the weather condition enum value for a standard Apple workout.

I know it exists because I can see it when I look at the data using the Apple Fitness App. Any suggestions?

[image]

```
        func asyncWorkout() async throws -> () {
        
        let workoutTypeValue: HKWorkoutActivityType = .running

        // custom/compound predicate formation
        let predicate1 = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date().addingTimeInterval(-5*24*60*60), end: Date().addingTimeInterval(-3*24*60*60), options: .strictStartDate)
        let predicate2 = HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: workoutTypeValue)
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])

        var myAnchor: HKQueryAnchor?
       
        let anchorDescriptor =
        HKAnchoredObjectQueryDescriptor(
            predicates: [.workout(predicate)],
                anchor: myAnchor)

        // Wait for the current results.
        let results = try await anchorDescriptor.result(for: healthStore)

        // Process the results.
        let addedSamples = results.addedSamples
        let deletedSamples = results.deletedObjects

        // Do something with the results here.
        for sample in addedSamples {
            // sample is a HKWorkout sample
            print("sample meta: \(String(describing: sample.metadata))")
                        
        }
                
        print("added samples(\(addedSamples.count)):\(addedSamples)")
        print("deletedSamples(\(deletedSamples)):\(deletedSamples)\n\n")

        // Update the anchor.
        myAnchor = results.newAnchor
        
    }
```

The print statement output is:

sample meta: Optional(["HKWeatherTemperature": 70.196 degF, "HKAverageMETs": 7.43516 kcal/hr·kg, "HKIndoorWorkout": 0, "HKTimeZone": America/New_York, "HKWeatherHumidity": 3600 %, "HKElevationAscended": 5097 cm])

Answer (score -1):

I just finished getting this working. Here is the code I used to access the metadata for a workout:

```
func getMetadata(for workout: HKWorkout) -> WorkoutMetadata {
    var workoutMetadata = WorkoutMetadata(mets: HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.kilocalorie().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.gramUnit(with: .kilo)).unitDivided(by: HKUnit.hour()), doubleValue: 0), elevationAscended: nil, indoorWorkout: 0, timeZone: "", humidity: 0.0, temperature: 0.0)
    var elevationAscended: Double?
    var weatherHumidity = 0.0
    var weatherTemperature = 0.0
    
    if let metadata = workout.metadata {
        let mets = metadata["HKAverageMETs"] as! HKQuantity
        let timeZone = metadata["HKTimeZone"] as! String
        let indoorWorkout = metadata["HKIndoorWorkout"] as! Int
        
        if let metaElevation = metadata[HKMetadataKeyElevationAscended] as? HKQuantity {
            let elevation = metaElevation.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.meter())
            elevationAscended = elevation
        } else {
            elevationAscended = nil
        }
                    
        if let metaHumidity = metadata[HKMetadataKeyWeatherHumidity] as? HKQuantity {
            let percentHumidity = metaHumidity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.percent())
            weatherHumidity = percentHumidity
        }
                    
        if let metaTemperature = metadata[HKMetadataKeyWeatherTemperature] as? HKQuantity {
            let degF = metaTemperature.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.degreeFahrenheit())
            weatherTemperature = degF
        }
        
        workoutMetadata = WorkoutMetadata(mets: mets, elevationAscended: elevationAscended, indoorWorkout: indoorWorkout, timeZone: timeZone, humidity: weatherHumidity, temperature: weatherTemperature)
    }

    return workoutMetadata
}
```

I save the data to a WorkoutMetadata variable I created so it's easy to access anywhere.

Comment: I was able to access those components of the Metadata too. I was looking for the weather condition  [link](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeyweathercondition) (clear, sunny, rainy, etc.).